# How to change localization in my android app without going to the settings?

Tags: android

Ok i have an application with 2 different languages (english and german), how to change them from my application? 
When i click the Language button im using intent to com.android.settings.LocalePicker and from there i select the language.
So instead of that i want to select English and German options from dialog box.
I know how to create the dialog box, but don't know how to change the locale.

Comment: just to know... how are you doing the localization? where are you saving the different languages text?

Comment: if you want the strings to be in german, you use folder values-de, or for french values-fr, italian-it and so on, and you put your strings.xml with the translated values for the strings.
Note that for some languages it's different, let's say if u use macedonian than u need to put the strings.xml into values-mk and values-en-rMK, or for simplified-chinese values-zh-rCN, traditional-chinese values-zh-rTW.
You can find more info in android sdk/dev docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application resources are fetched using the system local which isn't changeable from within an application.

The system settings screen uses a class (ActivityManagerNative) which isn't available via the SDK and thus can not be guaranteed to work between releases, and hence shouldn't be used in your code.

So your options are;

- Don't offer the functionality in your app
- Implement your own system for determining what setting the user has selected in your app and pulling the appropriate resources using your own code.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

1. create a normal android dialog with radio button selection of English & German
2. `OnCheckedChange ()`

write this to change the Language

```
Locale myLocale = new Locale(/*String selected*/);
Locale.setDefault(myLocale );

Configuration config2 = new Configuration();
config2.locale = myLocale ;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config2,
  getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```